# Checking form fields with AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to write a code that will check in a php file if username/mail has already been registered. The following code doesn't work because in check_fields() when check_field() is fired for both files the return is sent immediately, without waiting for the asynchronous query to finish. I don't want to use JQuery so I thought about doing the following :

- a function is linked to the onsubmit of the form
- a AJAX call is made to the server to launch a php file
- this file analyses the input and return a error response if it needs to : "field is empty", "email already used", "incorrect email adress", ect...
- when the AJAX call is finished a function (or callback) will be fired. This function will check the .textContent of the `<span id="username_err"></>` and `<span id="mail_err"></>` to see if the php has noticed to errors. If it's not blank (there's a problem in the input) the function return false to the initial function.
- the return value is sent back to the form
- if true, form is submitted to server...

That's what I would like to try out, is this ok ? Is there a way to do this without a promise ?

**[Original code]**

```
<html>

        <body>
          <form style="text-align:center" action="mama.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check()">

            <div class="username">
              <span id="label_username">Username :</span>
              <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
              <p id="username_err"></p>
            </div><br />

            <div class="mail">
              <span id="label_mail">Mail :</span>
              <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail"></input>
              <p id="mail_err"></p>
            </div><br />

            <input type="submit" id="envoyer" value="Envoyer" />
          </form>
        </body>

        <script>
          function check() {
            return check_fields(['username', 'mail']);
          }

          function check_fields(items) {
            var check = true;
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
              check_field(items[i]);
            };

            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
              var value = document.getElementById(items[i] + '_err').textContent;
              if (value != '') {
                check = false
              }
            };
            return check
          }

          function check_field(id) {
            var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
            ajax_php(id, value, 'check_field.php', function(returned_value) {
              document.getElementById(id + '_err').innerHTML = returned_value;
            });
          }

          function ajax_php(id, value, file, fn) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                fn(xmlhttp.responseText);
              }
            };
            xmlhttp.open('GET', file + '?' + id + '=' + value, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
          }
        </script>

        </html>
```

**[Possible solution]**

```
<html>

<body>
  <form style="text-align:center" action="mama.php" method="post" onsubmit="check(this)">

    <div class="username">
      <span id="label_username">Username :</span>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
      <p id="username_err"></p>
    </div><br />

    <div class="mail">
      <span id="label_mail">Mail :</span>
      <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail"></input>
      <p id="mail_err"></p>
    </div><br />

    <input type="submit" id="envoyer" value="Envoyer" />

  </form>
</body>

<script>
  function check_fields(form, items) {
    var success = true;

    function check_field(i) {
      var id = items[i];
      var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
      ajax_php(id, value, 'check_field.php', function(returned_value) {
        document.getElmentById(id + '_err').textContent = returned_value;
        if (returned_value != '') {
          success = false;
        }
        if (++i < items.length) {
          check_field(i); // Check the next field
        } else if (success) { // reached the last field with no errors
          form.submit();
        }
      });
    }
    check_field(0);
  }

  function check(form) {
    check_fields(form, ['username', 'mail']);
    return false; // prevent form submission
  }

  function ajax_php(id, value, file, fn) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        fn(xmlhttp.responseText);
      };
    };
    xmlhttp.open('GET', file + '?' + id + '=' + value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  };
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `.innerText`, use `.textContent`. `innerText` is not standard and doesn't exist in FireFox.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar I'll modify it. Any other help ?

Comment: Since AJAX is asynchronous, you can't check the `textContent` right after the loop. You have to do it in the callback function. What you should do is chain the AJAX calls: check the first field, then in its callback function check the next field, and so on. If you get through all the fields successfully then the last callback submits the form.

Comment: Ok @Barmar I've edited the code snippet. If they are all linked and and for exemple the first field has an error, it won't check the next fields, right ?

Comment: It depends on how you code it. There's nothing stopping you from doing the next validation check when the previous one shows an error. You could set a variable that holds whether any of them got an error, and at the very end check this variable before submitting the form. This will allow you to mark all the wrong fields instead of just the first one.

Comment: If you use jQuery, you could make use of the jquery-validate plugin. It has a `remote:` option that allows you to use an AJAX call to validate a field, and it takes care of all of this for you.

Comment: Another solution would be to use promises, and then at the end of the loop you can resolve all the promises.

Comment: But at the end, it comes back to the return problem, my variable will still be in the function. How will I make it reach the form onsubmit:"" ?

Comment: You can either use a global variable, or nest the `ajax_php` function within `check_fields` so that the callback function can assign to a variable in `check_fields`.

Comment: Whichever function defines the AJAX callback needs to be nested into `check_fields`, since the important thing is that the callback is nested.

Comment: It looks like the inside of `check_field()` has access to the variable `check` but can't modify it (see first thread). At the end of the function, when there is `alert(check);` it displays _'true'_ instead of _'changed !'_

Comment: `alert(check)` is not in the callback function, so it's executed before any of the AJAX calls have returned. You shouldn't be using a `for` loop. Like I said, you have to send the next call from the callback of the previous check.

Comment: You can find lots of questions that show the pattern if you search SO for "[javascript] chain ajax call". Most of them show how to do it with jQuery, though.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how it's going to reach the end while staying in the callback function ;)

Comment: `check_field(items[0], function() { check_field(items[1], function() { check_field(items[2], function() { ... submit_form())))`

Comment: I'm writing an answer

Comment: Don't forget that these AJAX checks don't remove the necessity to validate the data again in the script that processes form submissions, because users can bypass the Javascript check.

Comment: Yes, I realised that, I'll have to check with php too

Comment: Please put back the original code from the question. The comments and answers only make sense in the context of that question.

Comment: sure, i've edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chain the AJAX calls for each field. The callback for field `i` submits the AJAX call to check field `i+1`, and so on. The last callback submits the form if all were successful.

```
function check_fields(form, items) {
    var success = true;
    function check_field(i) {
        var id = items[i];
        var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
        ajax_php(id, value, 'check_field.php', function(returned_value) {
            document.getElementById(id + '_err').textContent = returned_value;
            if (returned_value != '') {
                success = false;
            }
            if (++i < items.length) {
                check_field(i); // Check the next field
            } else if (success) { // reached the last field with no errors
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    }
    check_field(0);
}

function check(form) {
    check_fields(form, ['username', 'mail']);
    return false; // prevent form submission
}
```

The form should contain:

```
onsubmit="return check(this)"
```

Comment: At the moment, the page redirects directly to the page... Also, it seems you have forgotten a `)` just before the `checkfields(0);`. I've added a new snippet in the first post.

Comment: I've corrected it. `check_field(0)` shouldn't be inside `check_field()`.

Comment: In my opinion it is better to handle `onchange` events of the fields of interest. Probably initially set submit button `disabled` and enable it when all checks pass.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev That's certainly another way to do it. jquery-validate does both: it checks first at submit time, and after that it re-checks while you edit (but this can be changed with options).

Comment: Still doesn't work, I've added the php file in the snippet so you can see.

Comment: Do you have a `mama.php` script? That's where the `action` points to for form submission.

Comment: I don't have one, but it shouldn't redirect me anyway since I have an empty field...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `return` in the `onsubmit`, so it wasn't preventing the normal submission.

Comment: It's a typo, can't you see it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it ;)

Comment: Now working. You have made my week sir, thank you so much for the help ! I'll keep this thread up, if I get some related issues...

Comment: I have improved my php file to allow some deeper verifications. When I tested the form earlier, I noticed something but didn't think of a solution. When all fields are wrong, all error messages appear, then if I fill it all up and send it, I have to wait for all the error message to disappear (due to the loop) before being redirected. Any idea to solve this ?

Comment: You could create an object that holds the values of each field. When you go through the loop again, check if the value has changed since the previous time -- if not, clear the error field and skip that AJAX call.